# How to save solutions in CPLEX OPL before run is complete

Tags: cplex, opl

I am running a large problem in CPLEX OPL and it takes over 150  hrs to get to some solutions on a fairly specd up computer, but at that point CPLEX crashes and closes. I have been trying to run it several times but without success of getting any results.

I have also increased the Gap tolerance to 30% for it to stop earlier but did not help.

I have the results being written to excel.

Is there any way that CPLEX will keep saving the best solution at any point of time into excel ? The idea behind my question is I do not want to lose the solutions found when it crashes. And command like "save the solution found"

Appreciate any quick help please.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on the "Post-Process Feasible Solutions" option.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry for coming back so late as it took me considerable time to run the problem. Somehow CPLEX is still crashing and not writing back to excel. I had some .dat files created using some lines like below. The dat files are being created but the solutions are no where close to optimal. ANy further suggestions shall be highly appreciated. I have also tried putting the gap to 30%, but didnt help. Anything to stop CPLEX from crashing - or leads on why it crashes.  
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("optscheduleXbmt.dat");
  o.writeln(solXbmt);
  o.close();